# What causing this error in in flutter run?

Tags: android, flutter

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:.
> Required by:
> project :app

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 37s

i tried updating dependencies code clean upgrade channel and still stuck on this error do someone has solution on this

Comment: welcome! Did you try getting details via the `--info` and `--debug` options? I _think_ this can be done by a command line such as `flutter build --info` or maybe `cd android; ./gradlew build --info`. Also does the project import firebase? If not, it won't find `firebase-core`.

Comment: Show app/build.gradle file.

Comment: could you share your  firebase-core version